# imported function calling function from original file

Tags: python, import

I have a Python program *A* that imports another program *B*.

Program *A* has a function `foo` and main classes and global variables etc.

Program *B* has a function `bar`.

Program *A*'s main function is ran user input during runtime is bar, so *A* calls bar: `B.bar(stuff)`.

`B.bar()` tries to call `A.foo()`. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you design it like this? It's just asking for trouble. Put `foo()` and `bar()` in the same file.

Comment: program b is written by the user to preprocess before calling a function. I guess B could just return the name of foo and A could call it after returning

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to avoid doing this as much as possible, e.g. have a third script `C` containing `foo` to avoid anything circular.

One workaround otherwise is to write `B` like so:

```
def bar():
    from A import foo
    foo()
```

and to not import `A` at the top level. This way the import only happens when `bar` is called so `A` is already fully loaded by then and you won't get an import error.